# MYSQL JOIN to create filters

Tags: mysql

I have tried to find a solution by searching stackoverflow alot, but couldn't make it. I'm sorry if I'm posting a posible duplicate which has already been answered.

I have 3 tables:

1) products (product_id(PRI), category_id(FOREIGN), product_en)

2) characteristics (characteristic_id (PRI), category_id(FOR), characteristic_en)
and

3) product_chacacteristics (misspelled) including (product_chacacteristic_id (PRI), characteristic_id (FOR), product_id (FOR), value_en)

the idea is to have products and characteristics, both categorized by category, which are combined in the third table where values are given. Fon instance:

Product A a has 2 characteristics, power consumption and light color with values 10 Watt and White respectively (only one value per characteristic is allowed).

I have created a small system to show products along with filters, which combine characteristics and values and reduce results. My current query looks like this when 2 filters apply:

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_chacacteristics 
    ON products.product_id = product_chacacteristics.product_id 
WHERE products.active = 1 
    AND products.category_id = 13 
    AND products.sub_category_id = 21 
    AND ((product_chacacteristics.characteristic_id = '7' 
    AND product_chacacteristics.value_en = '10 Watt') 
    AND (product_chacacteristics.characteristic_id = '8' 
    AND product_chacacteristics.value_en = 'White')) 
GROUP BY products.product_id 
ORDER BY products.product_order
```

and returns 0 rows (should return 2).... if one filter applies it works ok... i.e.

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_chacacteristics 
    ON products.product_id = product_chacacteristics.product_id 
WHERE products.active = 1  
    AND products.category_id = 13 
    AND products.sub_category_id = 21 
    AND ((product_chacacteristics.characteristic_id = '8' 
    AND product_chacacteristics.value_en = 'White')) 
GROUP BY products.product_id 
ORDER BY products.product_order
```

if OR is USED between filters

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
JOIN product_chacacteristics 
    ON products.product_id = product_chacacteristics.product_id
WHERE products.active = 1 
    AND products.category_id = 13 
    AND products.sub_category_id = 21 
    AND ((product_chacacteristics.characteristic_id = '7' 
    AND product_chacacteristics.value_en = '10 Watt') 
    **OR** (product_chacacteristics.characteristic_id = '8' 
    AND product_chacacteristics.value_en = 'White')) 
GROUP BY products.product_id 
ORDER BY products.product_order
```

It returns 5 rows and seems like the filtering is done only via the first filter and not combined

However there can be more than 3 or 4 filters in a query which are included by a small function that I have created.

I would be gratefull if someone can help me with the query above (2 filters) so that I can understand how to proceed....

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you re-enter the queries with decent formatting? Use the `{}` markup for Code, not the quotation markup, so that formatting will be retained.

Comment: @Barmar its edited correctly

Comment: One long line with a scroll bar isn't much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need a separate `JOIN` for each characteristic.

```
SELECT products.* FROM products

    <join for characteristic 7 and value X>

    <join for characteristic 8 and value Y>

WHERE 
-- Condition for all products
( products.active = 1 AND products.category_id = 13 AND products.sub_category_id = 21 )
AND
(
       -- Here the conditions on the values
)
ORDER BY products.product_order
```

Each JOIN will be of the form

```
    LEFT JOIN product_chacacteristics AS f1
    ON (products.product_id = f1.product_id 
        AND f1.characteristic_id = ? AND f1.value_en = ?)


    LEFT JOIN product_chacacteristics AS f2
    ON (products.product_id = f2.product_id 
        AND f2.characteristic_id = ? AND f2.value_en = ?)


    ...
    WHERE
    ...

        (f1.value_en = ?) OR (f2.value_en = ?)
```

So you can describe each condition with the following parameters:

```
- progressive number (goes into "f1, f2, ..." alias)
- characteristic id (e.g. 7)
- its value
```

and then you have another parameter that says whether you're using OR or AND. I'd advise against using complex expressions - just use all OR's, or all AND's.

Each time you call the "filter" function you should get back four separate objects:

```
- the SQL for the JOIN clause
- the two values for the JOIN clause binding
- the SQL for the WHERE clause
- the value (equal to the second one above) for the WHERE binding.
```

The pseudocode (PHP) would be something like:

```
$bigJoin = '';
$values1 = array();
$bigWhere = "( products.active = ? AND products.category_id = ? AND products.sub_category_id = ? )";
$values2 = array( 1, 13, 21 );

foreach ($filters as $i => $filter) {
    list($join, $joinvals, $where, $wherevals) = addFilter($i, $filter[$i]);
    $bigJoin .= $join;
    $values1 = array_merge($values1, $joinvals);
    $bigWhere .= " {$AND_or_OR} ( {$where} )";
    $values2 = array_merge($values2, $wherevals);
}

$SQL    = "SELECT products.* FROM products "
        . $bigJoin
        . " WHERE "
        . $bigWhere;
$values = array_merge($values1, $values2);

// prepare statement, bind $values, and execute.
```

Comment: will try it asap, why do you mention unfortunately? is the logic behind it wrong?

Comment: I think he means that it's unfortunate that doing this common operation requires such a complex query.

Comment: hope so, i found no other way of doing this

Comment: I have added a SQL Fiddle to better show how the finished query looks. This uses only two characteristics and two filters, but you can add as many as you want... within reason :-) . Find it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f1e/5/0

Comment: @lserni works like a charm. I have used your Revision 1 answer and it is amazing... knowledge accepted!